# Are the Egyptians the only ones to have carved the dead's biography on the coffin?

Tags: cultural-history, egypt

I know that Egyptians did it. (See [Hornedjitef's coffin](http://culturalinstitute.britishmuseum.org/asset-viewer/mummy-of-hornedjitef-inner-coffin/vgHJIobGkBxTQg?hl=en))

It is very interesting to me that they carved a biography on the coffin that was to be buried - not to mention that it was the inner coffin, so no one would see it.

Are there other cultures that have or had this kind of burial custom?

Have historians identified some possible reasons?

Comment: How will you select the authoritative answer?

Comment: I believe the motivation for the action was to preserve the soul (the Rn if I recall). Since (AFAIK), no other culture shared this concept of the soul, I would not be surprised if this were an unusual practice.

Comment: This is also true of many modern people who write short epitaphs on graves.